# Public network configuration doesn't work on OSX, El Capitan

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm using vagrant 1.7.4 on Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.1. I configured public network like below.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", :bridge => 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)', ip:"192.168.18.31"
```

But I found it doesn't works on my mac but work on PC. I'm using virtual box 5.0.8 r103449. Also I turned off firewall too.

Answer (score 0):

Does the host network interface you want to route through exist on `eth0`? Running `ifconfig` on my Mac OS shows an adapter name matching pattern `en0`.

You can use multiple interfaces in the bridge parameter if you would like to attempt to use many:

```
bridge: [
  "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)",
  "eth0: Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet Controller",
]
```

The first network adapter that exists and can successfully be bridge will be used.

Comment: I changed the question for wrong configuration I wrote. But it doesn't work. Is there any hint?

Comment: I tried the configuration below. But it doesn't work.

   config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: ["en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)", "eth0"], ip:"192.168.18.31"